# Bibliography style jfe.bst - add description of paper

Tags: bibtex

I am using `jfe.bst` bibliography style. I only want to change the note format.

In particular, after each bibliographic entry I want to add (optionally) a description of the paper, e.g.

```
\bibitem[{Arrow and Debreu(1954)}]{arrow_1954}
 Arrow, K.~J., Debreu, G., 1954. Existence of an equilibrium for a competitive
economy. Econometrica: Journal of the Econometric Society pp. 265--290.
\\[5pt] {\footnotesize In this paper Arrow and Debrue do blah blah blah}
```

in order to print something like

---

Arrow, K. J., Debreu, G., 1954. Existence of an equilibrium for a competitive
economy. Econometrica: Journal of the Econometric Society pp. 265-290.

In this paper Arrow and Debrue do blah blah blah...

---

Where the description has the same size as the footnotes. Is there an easy way to do this? I tried to change the `.bst` file but I couldn't get it to work.

## Minimal Example

Suppose the tex file is the following

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}
\citet{arrow_1954} does that.

\bibliography{temp}        %use a bibtex bibliography file refs.bib
\bibliographystyle{jfe}  %use the plain bibliography style

\end{document}
```

The bst file may be found [here](http://faculty.haas.berkeley.edu/stanton/texintro/jfe/jfe.sty). The temp.bib file contains only one entry

```
@article{arrow_1954,
  title={Existence of an equilibrium for a competitive economy},
  author={Arrow, Kenneth J and Debreu, Gerard},
  journal={Econometrica: Journal of the Econometric Society},
  pages={265--290},
  year={1954},
  publisher={JSTOR},
  note = {The paper is about that and that and shows that}
}
```

The produced .bbl file is

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\expandafter\ifx\csname natexlab\endcsname\relax\def\natexlab#1{#1}\fi

\bibitem[{Arrow and Debreu(1954)}]{arrow_1954}
Arrow, K.~J., Debreu, G., 1954. Existence of an equilibrium for a competitive
  economy. Econometrica: Journal of the Econometric Society pp. 265--290, the
  paper is about that and that and shows that.

\end{thebibliography}
```

I want to change the jfe.bst file so that the produced .bbl file to be

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\expandafter\ifx\csname natexlab\endcsname\relax\def\natexlab#1{#1}\fi

\bibitem[{Arrow and Debreu(1954)}]{arrow_1954}
Arrow, K.~J., Debreu, G., 1954. Existence of an equilibrium for a competitive
  economy. Econometrica: Journal of the Econometric Society pp. 265--290. 
\\[5pt] \footnote{The paper is about that and that and shows that}

\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Thank you! I edited the question. Should I add something more?

Comment: I think, it's quite good at the moment. The `*.bst` experts will find an answer soon ;-)

Comment: Are you sure you mean `\footnote{Note...}` and not `{\footnotesize Note...}`? The first will try to create footnotes in your bibliography. (And this will look very odd after a vertical space of 5pt!) The second will switch to the same size of font as is used in footnotes. (More-or-less.)

Comment: Yes.. after the bib entry I want to live some space (e.g. 5pt) and add a discription whose font size will be "footnotesize" or scriptsize... the size is not that important..